# how setup automatically permission for the maillog file on redhat

Tags: redhat, file-permissions

like in the title, I would like to know which file I've to modify 
to setup the permission on the maillog file as 0644.
I know that is a bad practice but I need it otherwise my script fail everytime.
I am using redhat 5.6 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using syslog, migrate to rsyslog or syslog-ng.

rsyslog: [`$FileCreateMode`](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_filecreatemode.html) is already set to 0644 by default.

syslog-ng:

```
filter f_mail { facility(mail); };
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/maillog" perm(0644)); };
log { source(s_local); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
```

Comment: quanta I am using **sysklogd** so in this case what you propose? I've found this article, [link]http://www.linuxhelp.in/2010/10/how-to-configure-syslog-server-or.html[link] but here the usmak is setup as 077 and the permission about the maillog in my case are 0644 so, now I am little bit confused.

Comment: migrate to rsyslog or syslog-ng if possible.